# Plugin development: Use flutter package plugin for specific platform only (e.g. Android but not iOS)?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to use a package plugin for only 1 (or specific) platform, e.g. "iOS, but not Android or Web"? For example, [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) supports Android, iOS, macOS and Web, but I only want it to be installed on Android where FCM is required. I will support other platforms with my own code/ other libraries.

I do not want the plugin to be registered on iOS because it may be causing a crash/ interfering with my application because it does Objective-C method swizzling. I guess I don't want it's `registerWithRegistrar` method called.

Note: this is **different** to supporting specific platforms. i.e. I still support Android and iOS, I just don't want one plugin to register on iOS. Having thought about this more, I don't just want to prevent plugin registration, but also compilation. This is because the compilation step can affect the build/ other plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Background

### `GeneratedPluginRegistrant`

A class is autogenerated to register all plugins:

#### Android, `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java`

```java
@Keep
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.ably.flutter.plugin.AblyFlutterPlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin());
  }
}
```

#### iOS, `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m`

```objectivec
@implementation GeneratedPluginRegistrant

+ (void)registerWithRegistry:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistry>*)registry {
  [AblyFlutterPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"AblyFlutterPlugin"]];
  [FLTFirebaseCorePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseCorePlugin"]];
  [FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin"]];
  [FlutterApnsPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FlutterApnsPlugin"]];
  [FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin"]];
}

@end
```

### Usage

You actually call that method, `registerWithRegistry:` in your AppDelegate, e.g.

#### Android

In your Android app's MainActivity:

```java
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
  }
}
```

#### iOS

In your iOS app's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`:

```objectivec
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
      [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = (id<UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>) self;
    }
    
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end
```

## Avoiding registration:

- Stop using `GeneratedPluginRegistrant`.
- **Caveat:** From now on, you'll need to remember to update the generated code into new class whenever you add or remove package plugins.
- **Caveat**: Unfortunately this doesn’t actually avoid the compilation/ build step. For example, the plugin's `AndroidManifest.xml` will still be merged into your applications Manifest.

### Android

Implement `PluginRegistrant.java` by copying the contents from `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java`. Call `PluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);` **instead**.

### iOS

Implement `PluginRegistrant.m` by copying the contents from `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m`. Call `[PluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];` **instead**.

### Further questions

Not necessarily hard questions, but I'm leaving this for later. :)

- How exactly does `GeneratedPluginRegistrant` know which plugins to register? (read the code generator)

Comment: How do i exclude package plugin for web?