# Native-only (C/C++) Flutter plugin

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, native

#### Problem

I am currently writing a small Flutter plugin in which I use some third-party C++ dependencies. In order to use it on both iOS and Android I am writing it in C++.
That part works fine.

However, generating a plugin with `flutter create -t plugin my_plugin` will also add Kotlin/Java sources to the Android part (and their equivalent to iOS). 
My issue is that I don't think I need these files. I assume their compilation takes some time, and they also add complexity to the project at first glance.

#### Solution attempt

I have found information on [making native-activity apps](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_na), but I am not making an app.

There is also an [issue on the flutter repository](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33227) discussing native-only plugins, but as far as I can tell there is no canonical way yet.

If I simply remove the `*.java` file in `android/src/main/org/my_plugin` I get an error

> The plugin `my_plugin` doesn't have a main class defined in

I cannot test the iOS side of things right now, but a similar problem would probably emerge.

#### Question

How can I get rid of all Java/Kotlin and ObjectiveC/Swift files in this Flutter plugin?
Any tips even only about the Android part would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818599/plugin-development-use-flutter-package-plugin-for-specific-platform-only-e-g this can help

Comment: @Ruchit Thank you for the comment! I fail to see how the link is related, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I don't believe you can do it without android/ios files. The thing is that native C code needs to be compiled per platform and needs to be linked with android library or ios framework.
I'm writing a tutorial on how to do it, but I'm still in process. I've implemented android part, but iOS is still in progress. Will post link here, once I'm done